# WinUI 3 - Navigate to a NavigationViewItem in Code

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have created a **NavigationView** which contains multiple items and an item with various menu items in it:

```xml
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Home" helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="Program.ViewModel.HomeViewModel">
    </NavigationViewItem>
    <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="List" helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="Program.ViewModel.ListViewModel">
    </NavigationViewItem>
    <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Details" helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="Program.ViewModel.DetailsViewModel">
    <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="SummaryViewItem" x:Uid="Details_Summary" helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="Program.ViewModel.SummaryViewModel">
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Details_Distances" helpers.NavigationHelpers.NavigateTo="Program.ViewModel.DistancesViewModel">
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Details_Location" helpers.NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="Program.ViewModel.LocationViewModel">
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
    </NavigationViewItem>
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

The "**DetailsViewModel**" contains code to collect information for its sub-pages, and the "**Details**" page is a blank page.

Sub-pages contain views and fields to show information in an organized fashion.

I want to achieve that when the user clicks on the "**Details**" navigation item, the program runs the associated ModelView and automatically navigates to the "**Summary**" page.

I have added the following code in the "**Details**" ModelView:

```cs
public async void OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter)
{
    //Other functions
    
    NavigationHelper.SetNavigateTo(ShellPage.SummaryNavigationItem, typeof(SummaryViewModel).FullName);
}
```

And this in Shell's code-behind to make "**SummaryViewItem**" accessible:

```cs
public static NavigationViewItem SummaryNavigationItem;

public ShellPage(ShellViewModel viewModel) {

    SummaryNavigationItem = SummaryViewItem;
}
```

but, it does not navigate to the "**Summary**" page, instead shows the "**Details**" page, which is blank.

How can I achieve this?

more information:
Code of **NavigationHelper** (copied from sample WinUI 3 app)

```cs
public static void SetNavigateTo(NavigationViewItem item, string value) => item.SetValue(NavigateToProperty, value);

public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigateToProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NavigateTo", typeof(string), typeof(NavigationHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `SetNavigateTo` doesn't do the navigation. It sets the destination when the `NavigationViewItem` is selected. So this line:

```cs
NavigationHelper.SetNavigateTo(ShellPage.SummaryNavigationItem, typeof(SummaryViewModel).FullName);
```

is setting that when **SummaryNavigationItem** is selected navigate to the corresponding page for **SummaryViewModel**, which is already set in ShellPage.xaml.

Then you might want to change this line to:

```cs
_navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SummaryViewModel).FullName!);
```

but this will fail. It seems that this doesn't work when you try to navigate while navigating. In your case, you are trying to navigate to **SummaryViewModel** while navigating to **DetailsViewModel**.

In order to achieve what you are trying to do:

1. Remove the `NavigationHelper` at **Details**'s `NavigationViewItem`.
2. Name the NavigationViewItem for **Details** and create an **Tapped** event handler.

```xml
<NavigationViewItem x:Name="Details" Tapped="Details_Tapped" x:Uid="Details"/>
```

3. Use the **ViewModel** to navigate to wherever you want.

```cs
private void Details_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This is an example how you can navigate, 
    // but you might want to create an method in the ViewModel 
    // and do your pre-navigation process there.
    ViewModel.NavigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(ListDetailsViewModel).FullName!);
}
```

Comment: It does what i exactly wanted :)